# How long a ParseCloud.callFunction() may take?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a portion of code that starts a new thread and calls `ParseCloud.callFunction()`. Let's say that the remote cloud function is fast but I have a bad connection, so the transmission becomes very slow... 
Is there a timeout system that throws a ParseException after a fixed delay before the actual result?

In other words... is the `ParseCloud.callFunction()` guaranteed to return success or error within a relatively short time, like 10 seconds?